# react-native use variable value to read constant value

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have some constants like this:

```
const tabIcon1 = require("../../../assets/tab/001.png");
const tabIcon2 = require("../../../assets/tab/002.png");
const tabIcon3 = require("../../../assets/tab/003.png");
const tabIcon4 = require("../../../assets/tab/004.png");
const tabIcon5 = require("../../../assets/tab/005.png");
```

I am making these constants' names dynamically like this:

```
let icon = 'tabIcon'+id;
```

How do i use `icon` variable to access constants' values?

Comment: Can you be me specific please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot construct/refer any variable name by assignment which you are doing.
You should instead make an icon object like the below:

```
const tabIcon1 = require("../../../assets/tab/001.png");
const tabIcon2 = require("../../../assets/tab/002.png");
const tabIcon3 = require("../../../assets/tab/003.png");
const tabIcon4 = require("../../../assets/tab/004.png");
const tabIcon5 = require("../../../assets/tab/005.png");

const icon = {
  tabIcon1,
  tabIcon2,
  tabIcon3,
  tabIcon4,
  tabIcon5
};
```

and access your icons using `icon.tabIcon1`, `icon.tabIcon2` and so on.